# Autowire a form in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Unable to understand

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Form\SomeFormType": argument "$parameterBag" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

If I remove the construct of the form and check debug:autowiring I get this though:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-32 pos]# bin/console debug:autowiring | grep Param
  Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBagInterface
  Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface
```

Not sure how to resolve outside of injecting parameters manually in `services.yml`

Comment: Can you post the constructor for your FormType?  Sure seems like it should work.  And does "bin/console debug:container | grep Param" return the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have configured autowire properly in your `config/services.yaml` file ?

Most important part:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true // <--- it should be true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
```

You can also make available to autowire single service:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface:
    autowire: true
```

---

Anyway I think you shouldn't pass whole ParameterBag into your form. You should pass values which you need while creating a form.

I bet you are doing something like:

```
$form = $this->createForm(App\Form\SomeFormType::class, $data, [
    'key' => 'value', //it should be also some options builder class
]);
```

You can pass some options in 3rd parameter, and you can access them inside SomeFormType:

```
class SomeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        dump($options); // will output parameters from createForm (['key' => 'value'])
    }
// ...
```

---

**Manual**

[Defining Services Dependencies Automatically (Autowiring)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

[Symfony Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html)